# Make Gson throw exception on parsing JSON with duplicated key

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I'm parsing simple JSON object with Gson. I want it to throw some error when key name is duplicated. E.g.

```
{
  a: 2,
  a: 3
}
```

In my case, Gson parses such JSON and sets a to 3. I want it to throw some exception.

I know I can parse JSON as map, and then Gson throws exception in such case, but only if the duplicated key is not nested in the map. If I have e.g. JSON like this:

```
{
  a: 2,
  b: {
    dup: 1,
    dup: 2
  }
}
```

Still, it is parsed without any exception and I have only one "dup" with value 2.

Can I somehow setup Gson to throw error in such case? Or to have duplicated entries in `JsonObject` instance, so that I can detect it myself (but I doubt that, as it would be invalid `JsonObject`)

Reproducible example

```
String json = "{\"a\":2, \"a\":3}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

prints out

```
{"a":3}
```

Comment: Can you add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can replicate what you're describing?

Comment: @dimo414 I've done that for them per my understanding.

Comment: It seems to me you should have the other end send valid JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks sometimes the JSON you want to parse isn't valid.  A parser should be able to detect that.

Comment: @dimo414 - http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html

Comment: @dimo414 - Then one should use a JSON parser which detects invalidity.  It doesn't need to be the same parser that is used to deserialize, necessarily.

Comment: @HotLicks I tried with a `JsonReader` with leniency set to `false` and it doesn't detect it.

Comment: Sure, such JSON is invalid. The problem is we keep configuration in it - humans write it. It's important, so I need this error detection. JSON seems really suitable for it, as we need key-value, arrays of objects etc. I was thinking also about YAML, but it seems it has the same problem, I was testing on http://instantyaml.appspot.com/

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Well, there are at least a dozen more to go.

Comment: Other Json parsers might catch this. Try those

Comment: Jackson has feature STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION

Comment: duplicate keys is valid json. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 "The names within an object SHOULD be unique". "should", but not required to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You may edit the source of gson a little bit. This is just a suggestion to understand how things work. I don't advice you to use this on a real/production environment.

Gson uses [com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java) while parsing a json string to a `JsonObject`. For testing issues you can copy that class into your project with the same name and package name. And edit its put method to not allow duplicate keys.

```
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("key == null");
    }

    // my edit here
    if(find(key, false) != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'" + key.toString() + "' is duplicate key for json!");
    }

    Node<K, V> created = find(key, true);
    V result = created.value;
    created.value = value;
    return result;
  }
```

2) Another clean solution is to define custom classes which are going to map to your json strings. Then write their custom [TypeAdapters](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.java)

3) Do it by using a [Deserializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.java)? I don't think it is possible. If you try to use it you'll see that you already have a jsonObject there which your duplicate keys are handled as one.

Comment: Yes I was already thinking about TypeAdapter and I'll try this.

Comment: Good ideas, but adding a TypeAdapter, well, then you need one for any custom class? That isn't sustainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
String json = "{\"a\":2, \"a\":3}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(json, mapType);
```

And if json is more complex than JsonObject can be used as map value type:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, JsonObject>>() {}.getType();
```