# eliminate duplicated key on parsing JSON

Tags: android, gson

```
Json from server 
           {
          "status": 1,
          "players": {
            "__v": 5,
            "_id": "52f719eb31f3b9b20500000c",
            "battingStyle": "Left Hand Batsman",
            "bowlingStyle": "Facing Batsman",
            "dob": "2000-02-09T06:01:49.144Z",
            "fname": "Muhammad",
            "playingRole": "Bowler",
            "sname": "Sami",
             "teams": [
                  {
                    "__v": 23,
                    "_id": "52f715b431f3b9b205000004",
                    "category": "Veteran‎s",
                    "name": "Golden Eagle",
                    "rating": 5,
                    "teamGender": "Men"
                  },
                  {
                    "__v": 17,
                    "_id": "52f715df31f3b9b205000005",
                    "category": "Veterans",
                    "name": "Choudhry Sports",
                    "rating": 5,
                    "teamGender": "Men"
                  }
                ],
             "grounds": [
                  {
                    "__v": 2,
                    "_id": "53381bb5f0bce0bd20000001",
                    "address": "6046 W Lake Sammamish Way Northeast, Redmond, WA 98052, United States",
                    "city": "Redmond",
                    "country": "United States",
                    "latitude": "",
                    "longitude": "",
                    "name": "Marymoor Park"
                  },
                  {
                    "__v": 2,
                    "_id": "53381bb5f0bce0bd20000001",
                    "address": "6046 W Lake Sammamish Way Northeast, Redmond, WA 98052, United States",
                    "city": "Redmond",
                    "country": "United States",
                    "latitude": "",
                    "longitude": "",
                    "name": "Marymoor Park"
                  }
                ]
        }
        }
```

And after j son parse Model has contain duplicate id 
                Player[
              id=1,
              _id=531029b207987409620000d6,
              battingStyle=RHB,
              bowlingStyle=RAOS,
              dob=2000-02-28T06: 15: 15.264Z,
              playingRole=BWL,
              sname=QadeerButt,
              fname=Tahir,
              gallery=[

```
          ],
          games=[
            Game[
              id=4,
              gameType=T20‎,
              name=TotallyCricketvsLahoreTiger,
              totalOvers=20,
              dateStarted=2014-06-18T19: 00: 00.000Z,
              dateEnded=2014-06-18T19: 00: 00.000Z,
              innings=[

              ],
              grounds=[
                Ground[
                  id=26,
                  address=14835SE18thPl,
                  Bellevue,
                  WA98007,
                  UnitedStates,
                  city=Bellevue,
                  country=UnitedStates,
                  name=RobinswoodPark
                ],
                Ground[
                  id=26,
                  address=14835SE18thPl,
                  Bellevue,
                  WA98007,
                  UnitedStates,
                  city=Bellevue,
                  country=UnitedStates,
                  name=RobinswoodPark
                ]
              ],
              teams=[
                Team[
                  id=30,
                  name=TotallyCricket,
                  category=Veterans,
                  teamGender=Men,
                  rating=5
                ],
                Team[
                  id=19,
                  name=LahoreTiger,
                  category=Under19,
                  teamGender=Men,
                  rating=3
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the Collection (maybe an arraylist?) already has an object with the id before storing a new one.

Comment: i have used GSon lib from parsing json creating model how can i have check this in library gson

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556332/make-gson-throw-exception-on-parsing-json-with-duplicated-key

Comment: I dont think modify the gson source is a proper solution for him

Comment: already used this solution changing  com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap class but unable to solve  @Override public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("key == null");
    }
    // my edit here
    if(find(key, false) != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'" + key.toString() + "' is duplicate key for json!");
    }
    Node<K, V> created = find(key, true);
    V result = created.value;
    created.value = value;
    return result;
  }

Comment: Well, a not so good way would be to just iterate over the collection and remove any duplicates manually but I think there might be a better way to solve this.

Comment: public Ground JsonParse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
  Ground ground = null;
  try {

   GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
   Gson gson = builder.create();
   ground = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getString("grounds")
     , Ground.class);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  return ground;
 }
so i iterate jsonObject

Comment: What you could also do is to use a Map with the id as the key in place of an ArrayList.

Comment: i have used ormlite and GSon in model class as @SerializedName("grounds")
 @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerLevel = 2)
 private Collection<Ground> grounds;

Comment: {"players":{"fname": "Tahir","grounds": [{"__v": 26,"_id": "53381c1bf0b","address": "14835 SE 18th Pl, Bellevue, WA 98007, United States","city": "Bellevue","country": "United States","latitude": "","longitude": "","name": "Robinswood Park"},{"__v": 26,"_id": "53381c1bf0bce0bd20000002","address": "14835 SE 18th Pl, Bellevue, WA 98007, United States","city": "Bellevue","country": "United States","latitude": "","longitude": "","name": "Robinswood Park"}],"teams": [{"__v": 30,"_id": "52f86b1d31f3b9b205000a58","category": "Veterans","name": "Totally Cricket","rating": 5,"teamGender": "Men"}]}}

Comment: i have duplicate in grounds,teams may be other object also _v duplicate from service so i have all object write this  if (!jsonArrayHasItem(secondJson, json.getInt("__v"))) {
        secondJson.put(json.getJSONObject(i));
   } however this is so long if i added new class model we write again code in this funtion for those newly added model

Comment: I have updated code on above question and in player model grounds has same id two object insert i have single object in ground because id has same

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is what the JSON shows. An JSON Array which contains duplicate JSON Objects.

You may want to valiate while parsing if the JSONObject already exists and copy it in another.

```
GSON gson = new GSON();

JSONArray json = new JSONArray(gson.toJson(yourobject));

JSONArray secondJson = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i <= json.length(); i++) {
if (!jsonArrayHasItem(secondJson, json.getInt("id")) {
     secondJson.put(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i));
}
}

public boolean jsonArrayHasItem(JSONArray jsonArray, int item) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      if (jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).has(item)) return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

not tested or compiled at all. just pseudocode.

Comment: i have used GSon lib from parsing json creating model how can i have check this in library gson

Comment: Its easy as hell. Just convert it as JSONArray and modify the JSON Data. Anyway, you should rethink your model if duplicate IDs shouldnt be used.

Comment: public Ground JsonParse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
  Ground ground = null;
  try {

   GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
   Gson gson = builder.create();
   ground = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getString("grounds")
     , Ground.class);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  return ground;
 }
so i have iterate jsonobject

Comment: Please try to understand the basics first. We gave you 2 possible solutions, try to understand and to use them

Comment: json.getInt("id") The method getInt(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: if (jsonArray.has(item)) and The method has(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: {"players":{"fname": "Tahir","grounds": [{"__v": 26,"_id": "53381c1bf0b","address": "14835 SE 18th Pl, Bellevue, WA 98007, United States","city": "Bellevue","country": "United States","latitude": "","longitude": "","name": "Robinswood Park"},{"__v": 26,"_id": "53381c1bf0bce0bd20000002","address": "14835 SE 18th Pl, Bellevue, WA 98007, United States","city": "Bellevue","country": "United States","latitude": "","longitude": "","name": "Robinswood Park"}],"teams": [{"__v": 30,"_id": "52f86b1d31f3b9b205000a58","category": "Veterans","name": "Totally Cricket","rating": 5,"teamGender": "Men"}]}}

Comment: Please update your code and the results you get, else it's hard to read. Ill fix and update onec your post is updated

Comment: i have duplicate in grounds,teams may be other object also _v duplicate from service so i have all object write this  if (!jsonArrayHasItem(secondJson, json.getInt("__v"))) {
        secondJson.put(json.getJSONObject(i));
   } however this is so long if i added new class model we write again code in this funtion for those newly added model

Comment: And player model game id duplicate insert and i have single object in Ground model